# How to label each column of an array in a math environment and also maintaining a global label for the whole equation?

Tags: cross-referencing, align, amsmath, arrays

I have an linear program displayed as an array inside an align environment:

```
\begin{align}\label{label1}
\begin{array}{lll}
    \max        & \sum_{v\in V} z^v\\
    \text{s.t.} & \forall v\in V:                  & \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^v=1\\
    & \forall v\in V,\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}: & y_i^v\leq\sum_{w\in N[v]}x_i^w\\
    & \forall v\in V,\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}: & z^v\leq y_i^v\\
    & \forall v\in V,\;\forall i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}: & x_i^v, y_i^v\in\{0,1\}.
\end{array}
```

I would like to globally label the whole equation (which I already do e.g. (14)) but before this label I would like to have a line with sub labels (a), (b), ... for each line of the array.

so that there is the a line on the right with the local array row label and a most outer right label as global equation label.

```
eq1 (a)
eq2 (b) (1)
eq3 (c)
```

Is something like this possible in latex?

Comment: That you can reference each line in array? That seems to be impossible (error `multiple label` ), however, you can simple give  tags in additional array column.

Comment: can I create exact representations of my linear programs without arrays and then find a solution as the one I am tried to describe?

Comment: People usually use `align` in `subequations` environment or specialized package for this (temporary I don't remember the name, I newer use it).

Comment: Zarko, yeah I know about those packages but at least I wasn't able to recreate an as well structured equation layout as I get when I use the `array` environment.